# DNS Problem with my Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dns

I have a problem with my Macbook Pro. I suspend it and if I should open it up and the wifi is connected and all looks pretty well. But I have no connection with my DNS Server. Other devices works well. I can ping all ip adresses but I can't resolve any hostnames.

My Router is a "Vodafone Easybox 903". I don't know what the problem is, and I don't know how I can solve it.

My Macbook is the only device with this problem. My girlfriends MacBook Pro, iPhones, Apple TV and my Ubuntu PC work without any Problems.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Google DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html) - it will solve the problem, but doesn't go very far as to explaining why it's only your computer experiencing it. It might be worth checking in your hosts file to see if there are any unexpected entries.

Open Terminal
Type "Sudo nano /etc/hosts"
Enter your admin password

Your ouput should be something similar to the following:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##

127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

Push ctrl + x to close when finished, and then you can close terminal. You may also have two more localhost entries - you're looking for anything with a * or any of the websites you use normally. I know SelfControl.app modifies this file and sometimes doesn't change it back.

Comment: Yes, i have taken an own bind9 Server and checked the query.log - the request came, the server answered, but my macbook pro runs in Timeout. Only a reboot of the MBP helps.